# apache storm: how to transform (make a new) tuple

Tags: kotlin, apache-storm

This is probably not the best practice in storm but we are working with a library that requires us to transform the values of a tuple in our bolt to filter out only objects of a certain class. I know how to do the filter, however, I'm not sure how I can put together a new tuple with the transformed (i.e., filtered) tuple:

```
override fun execute(input: Tuple?) {
  val filteredValues = input.values.filterIsInstance(MyClass::class.java)
  // ? how do I make a new tuple with filteredValues
  val newTuple = ...
  if (doExecute(newTuple)) {
    this.collector.ack(input)
  } else {
    this.collector.fail(input)
  }
}
```

where `doExecute` is out of our control and it only takes a tuple.

**EDIT**
I guess it's possible if I created a copy of the input tuple and just set the `values` of the copy to the `filteredValues`. However, I wonder if there's a more idiomatic way.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I also need to create a new Tuple object from another Tuple object by changing some of the values.

Answer (score 0):

I would just split your bolt in two. Have a bolt that does the filtering, and then have a second bolt that receives from the filtering bolt and calls `doExecute`.

Comment: Yes that will work. However, that option is not on the table for me.